# React Native 0.40 Network Request failed

Tags: android, react-native

Debugging network issues on an existing app. Using `fetch`, but everything seems to fail with a pretty generic

```
TypeError: Network request failed
```

I have debugged the issue further up the chain to the XMLHttpRequest response, and see

```
Expected ':status' header not present
```

as the response text.

Since this is an existing app, I need to try to push out a JS update, not a new app build to the existing Android customer base.

This doesn't appear to be an issue on the newer builds which are on the latest React Native, only these older builds.

UPDATE:

This seems to be the error: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1397

The cause is due to an issue with the underlying http lib on Android and this newer version of nginx. Moving the API to a different server has solved this.

Comment: Please post the relevant code that is bringing problems